# Will Adobe Flash be supported in iOS 5?

Tags: adobe-flash, ios

I now own an iPod Touch 4 with iOS 4.3.5 on it. I jailbroke it a while ago, but since it made me too many problems I reset it and it's now locked.

My question is, will the new iOS 5 is going to support flash videos such as from megavideo.com?

Comment: No. Adobe and Apple have made no plans to bring Flash to iOS.

Comment: Simple answer: no. Complicated answer: no, never, not a chance, not in a million years, never ever ever.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Flash videos, or more specifically, movies streamed via a Flash Object will likely never ever be officially supported in iOS as a first-party (built-in) feature.

Apple and Steve Jobs have a very firm stance against Adobe's Flash technologies, claiming that they perform poorly on mobile devices, cause the web browsing experience to be diminished, and drain battery life excessively.

Flash is not an announced feature in iOS 5.

Comment: OK. So is there going to be (or there is) any free decent workaround? Cuz I'm starting to think about getting rid of my iPod and get Galaxy player instead, Android does support Adobe Flash whether they like or not. Adobe Flash has too many customers de facto, and you have to serve these customers or give them an alternative that is let's say not directly supported but exists.

Comment: [Skyfire](http://www.skyfire.com/) is the answer to that question. Either the Skyfire Browser or Skyfire VideoQ, review their web site to determine which is relevant to you. iTunes App Store Links: [Skyfire Browser](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/skyfire-web-browser/id384941497?mt=8), [Skyfire VideoQ](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/skyfire-videoq-universal/id439822501?mt=8).

Comment: Do you know of anything for FREE?

Comment: Nope (11 more to go...)